# ALAsset was deprecated - Use PHAsset from Photos Framework

Tags: swift, metadata, uiimagepickercontroller, alassetslibrary, phphotolibrary

I am retrieving an image using

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) }
      let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
}
```

I can retrieve the image, also use the image to input to a button background or whatever else I would like, but I cannot seem to retrieve the metadata of the photo. Now, there is a lot of talk on various other locations on the interwebs of using `ALAssets` and their techniques for image data, BUT, `ALAssets` is deprecated as of recently. Since my image is not an image that the user just took, but instead an image choosing from the camera roll, I am unable to use :

`let metadata = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetaData] as! NSDictionary`

So, if anyone could point me in the correct direction as to how to get the metadata of an image that a user just picks from their camera roll, without using ALAssets, it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `PhotoKit` is only available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get images from camera roll then this would help :

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

let imageUrl = info["UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"]
let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([imageUrl], options: nil).firstObject as! PHAsset
print("location: " + String(asset.location))
print("Creation Date: " + String(asset.creationDate))

}
```

Comment: Ok, but where does asset come from? I guess that is where my confusion lies in using PHImageManager

Comment: PHImageManager will get all the images from the gallery taken with camera.

Comment: I see, how would I then retrieve only 1 image? I have their photo library pop up, and ask the user to pick the image they would like to use for my app. How do I know which 1 they pick?

Comment: what info you need while selecting image from gallery ?

Comment: I need to be able to retrieve the metadata, specifically the GPS location along with the TimeStamp that the photo was taken, from ANY photo of the user's choice inside their photo gallery.

Comment: Wow. That makes 100% sense, and was much simpler than what I was trying to do. Thanks for all the help, as this is my first time having done anything with Photos at all. I very much appreciate it.

Comment: info[@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"] returns null in iOS 10.

Comment: PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs was deprecated in iOS 11

Comment: Don't use this answer as `fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs` is deprecated in iOS11 & will be removed in future release.

Answer (score -1):

An Objective-C solution from [Muhammad Yawar Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36492522/1091539) answer:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{
    NSString * imageUrl = info[@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];
    PHAsset * asset = [[PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:[NSArray arrayWithObject:imageUrl] options:nil]firstObject];
    NSLog(@"location: %@",asset.location);
    NSLog(@"Creation Date: %@",asset.creationDate);
}
```